# Using grep to find lines between a set of numbers

Tags: unix, grep

I'm doing a Unix assignment for my class and I've run into a bit of a problem.  We are trying to output lines that have a number between 20-30.

Is there a way to use `grep` or `egrep` so that you can output a line that has a number that has limits, such as a number between 20 and 30 or a number less than 25?

Comment: Inclusive or exclusive? (20,30) or [20,30]?

Comment: How do you express 20-30 in terms of regex? (a) 20 to 29 is 2 followed by any digit. (b) 30 is just 30. So the entire range is just (a) OR (b). Any number less than 25 would use similar building blocks.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
grep '\(^\|\D\)\(2[0-9]\|30\)\(\D\|$\)' input
```

or, similarly:

```
grep '\(^\|[^0-9]\)\(2[0-9]\|30\)\([^0-9]\|$\)' input
```

or with the `-P` flag:

```
grep -P '(^|[^0-9])(2[0-9]|30)([^0-9]|$)' input
```

so basically, think of the possible strings you want to match and express them as patterns.

Comment: AFAIK, this assumes you have a version of `grep` with Perl regex (PCRE) support that auto-detects when the PCRE is used.  That might not apply on 'Unix' which is what the question is tagged with.  GNU `grep` does support PCRE, at least with an explicit `-P`.  Otherwise, this answer is good.  It does at least avoid selecting `200` and `120` and other such numbers which contain more than two digits.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, for some reason this does not work correctly with `-P`, any ideas?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, got it, I should not escape some operators with `-P`.

Comment: GNU `grep` greatly complicates things by trying to be all things to all people automagically.  Frankly, it doesn't help.  I like the idea of PCRE enabled with `-P`.  As I think you found out: `grep -P '(^|\D)(2\d|30)(\D|$)'` or `grep -E '(^|[^0-9])(2[0-9]|30)([^0-9]|$)'` work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple grep with regular expression

```
$-grep  -wE '(2[0-9]|30)' file_name
```

Comment: That (regex `'(2[0-9]|30)'`) would pick up 2001 and various other numbers.

Comment: Yes,that expression pick the values of 2001 to `20`01 ,I edited my post.****Thank you *****.

Comment: Yes, the GNU `grep` (and BSD `grep`, but not POSIX [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)) can use the `-w` option.  The parentheses aren't actually needed here, though they do no harm either.

Answer (score 0):

to grep for a value between 20-30 you can use this

```
egrep -e "[^0-9]2[0-9][^0-9]" -e "[^0-9]30[^0-9]" <file_name>
```

Comment: That (regexes `2[0-9]` and `30`) would pick up 2001 and various other numbers, unless you had a file with a name such as `22` in the current directory, whereupon it will pick up 22 (correct) and also 222, 122, 221, and other such numbers.  Enclose regexes in single quotes always — for sanity's sake.

Comment: Hi... nice observation.. have changed it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
 grep -wE '\b[2]{1}[0-9]{1}\b|30' file
```

Explanation:

```
[2]{1} --> find a number starting with one 2
[0-9]{1} --> The "2" is follored by any number but only repeated once
|30 --> And also finds "30" number.
```